# How to setup SSL for EC2 with ACM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

(I'm an AWS newb)

So I have a running EC2 instance and want to set up the SSL so it can serve HTTPS.

I found a [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html) from AWS to set up the SSL with external CA, or a [brief statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html) that ACM should be able to work with EC2, but seems not finding any step-by-step guide for this and I expect AWS should have done it with only a few clicks.

Do I need to use the ELB, even though my server is only running in ONE instance?

Comment: You can do SSL termination on EC2 but its very tricky (I've never managed it), and you cant use ACM. You can use an ELB, which is simple, but its very expensive if you're only running 1 EC2 instance. My advice would be to use CloudFront. Its very easy to setup, will perform SSL termination for you cheaply (using ACM), and comes with a whole host of benefits such as DDOS protection and content caching.

Answer (score 2):

ACM SSL certs **can't be used directly on instances** (except enclaves as indicated by Mark in the comments). They can only be used, as in your link, on load balances, CloudFront distro or API gateway. Thus, if you want to use ACM, you have to use either of these three services in-front of your EC2 instance.

But if you don't want to use them, then you need to get your SSL cert from a **third party**, not from ACM. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ along with [carebot](https://certbot.eff.org/) which provide free public SSL certificates. This means that you have to set it up yourself on the instance, usually done through a reverse proxy such as nginx.

Comment: They released ACM support for EC2 last year, but it requires the use of Nitro Enclaves and it looks like it only works with Nginx right now, and only on Amazon Linux 2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enclaves/latest/user/nitro-enclave-refapp.html

Comment: @MarkB Thanks Mark. I know about enclaves, but it does not seem to be the case that OP is using enclaves. They have very narrow use-case, thus I when I write it does not work on instances nor OP does not mention it, I mean a lack of support in general case.

Comment: The OP linked in his question to the AWS documentation that states enclaves are how you integrate ACM with EC2, and asked for a guide on how to do that, so he definitely mentioned it. Enclaves are part of EC2 instances, so saying "it doesn't work on instances" isn't correct.

Comment: @MarkB Fair enough. I updated the answer.